# Identity Server 4 as Web API for Angular SPA

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, openid-connect

We are building an application with `Angular 10` based front-end and `.NET Core 3.1` based `Web APIs`. For Authentication we want to use `Identity Server 4`. I want to know if we can have `Identity Server` integrated with our `Web API` project instead of having separate application for `Identity Management` which would save us some cloud hosting charges too. I am wondering if this is good approach to follow or there is any security flaw in this and will I be following the `OAuth2` and `OpenID Connect` specs using this approach.

Answer (score 1):

It should be over solution when you create `Identity Server 4` as your Authorization. In fact you can build `Asp .Net Identity` with providing JWT to  handle your Authorization mechanism. That is a simplest way and boost your development instead of pushing to learn and handle `Identity Server 4`.

For a security, you should [read this guideline](https://curity.io/resources/architect/api-security/jwt-best-practices/), most of this guideline is covered in `.Net Core`. `JWT` is still fine for handling security aspects.

Remembered, `Identity Server 4` is only used when you have a plan for sharing your `authenticated users` cross multiple apps. If you don't have, you don't want to apply it.

Comment: I am trying to understand what you are suggesting here, use `Asp .NET Identity` within the Web API project for handing Authentication and Authorization? But then will it be okay if I use Angular pages as front-end and use Web API methods for Authentication and Authorization? Will my application be secure enough?

Comment: Yes, it is. Dont be mistaken about thinking ASP .Net  Identity server source code must stay in the same API server. Each Api server can be configured to validate via AuthenticationScheme=JsonBearerToken itself. And if you can choose to build one monolith Api with containing Identity, it is still working. Angular just retrieve jwt and attach to Http Header to perform Api.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is common scenario and there is built-in helper methods in IDS4 such as `AddLocalApiAuthentication` to simplify it.

Here is a sample: https://github.com/brockallen/IdentityServerAndApi

Checkout here for more details: https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/add_apis.html?highlight=AddLocalApiAuthentication#adding-more-api-endpoints